# how to store data with ArrayList using Java RMI between server and client?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, rmi

I've been asked for my final project to develop a GUI system that provides information about (criminals) Using **Java RMI**.

Some info about the system:

- The client doesn't have any data just request it from RMI Server and
  view.
- All data stored inside an **ArrayList** in RMI Server.
- Client Requirements are :
  (View List,  View criminal Information, Refresh List, Search for criminal)

*I'm not asking for the whole implementation,, just enough code and tips that might help me out and making continue with a good understating of the system.*

**My Code so far..**

The Service Class

```
import java.rmi.server.*;
import java.rmi.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Service extends UnicastRemoteObject
    implements Interface {

ArrayList Info = new ArrayList();

public Service() throws RemoteException {
super();
  }

public  add (Person p) {
  return Info.add(p);
  }

public  update(Person p) {

  }

public int delete(Person p) {

  }

public ArrayList findByName(String criteria) {

    }
  }
```

The Interface Class

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public interface Interface extends Remote {

public int add(Person p) throws RemoteException;

public int update(Person p) throws RemoteException;

public int delete(Person p) throws RemoteException;

public ArrayList findByName(String criteria) throws RemoteException;

 }
```

Person Class

```
public class Person {

private String name;
private String address;
private String mobile;

public Person(String name, String address, String mobile) {
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.mobile = mobile;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getMobile() {
    return mobile;
}

public void setMobile(String mobile) {
    this.mobile = mobile;
}

}
```

I made a Jframe Class that stores Criminals data into Array List but it's not connected to anything just yet..like in the Pic below ,, I can add,delete criminals and update their data from the table aside..

[image]

The Client Class is Jframe and and it shows the criminals I stored before in table and I can select anyone and it will show their info without being able to update it, also it must enable the client to search for a specific criminal by name.

The problem NOW is that I don't know how to connect everything together, all data must be at the server and the client only request it but I don't know how exactly i suppose to make the info I stored to be able to show at the client!?
I need Tips anything that can make me understand how this should work?

**Thank you in advance ..**

Comment: You are reinventing the wheel. Using NetBeans (for example), you can automatically set this up without having to create a whole new plumbing system

Comment: hello,, I'm using NetBeans but how this solves the problem ?

Comment: https://netbeans.org/features/java-on-server/web-services.html

Comment: well, thx but I must use RI to do this, then later i will use WS to add another feature but every step at time :)

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You have `public ArrayList findByName(String criteria)` which the client calls the server with and gets the `ArrayList`. Now just do whatever you need to do with it in the client.

Comment: And don't call your interface "Interface ".